# KB980408: Fix for Explorer freezing: does anyone know what app caused it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, freeze, windows-update, compatibility

Microsoft released an update for Windows 7 today (Tuesday, April 27, 2010): [KB980408](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980408):

***The April 2010 stability and reliability update for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 is available.***

The update fixes, among other things:

> Windows Explorer may stop responding
>   for 30 seconds when a file or a
>   directory is created or renamed after
>   certain applications are installed.

I'm not experiencing it on my own Windows 7 machine, but two colleagues at work were experiencing the problem. I would **really** like to know what applications were causing problems.

Microsoft will never call out the misbehaving applications. I want to know what software I should be ridiculing and insulting (and avoiding in the future).

Did anyone who was experiencing this problem isolate the applications?

Comment: It may not be the fault of the applications, at least not fully. If the fix is to OS DLL's, it may be that the issue was, at least partially, in the OS. It is likely caused by a combination of factors and is exposed by how some apps do specific things.

Comment: i know it *could* be the fault of Explorer. But Windows ships with an application compatibility list containing over 1,300 applications. i'm confident that a 3rd party product is doing something wrong, and Microsoft is shipping a fix to work around someone else's bug. Adobe products themselves get 25 appcompat fixes.

Comment: Click `Start` and type in `Reliability History` look when the crash happened and right click it and `View Technical Details` that information might help

Comment: Two weeks ago, I experienced this problem for some computers in our network! In our case in our 50 networked computer 4 or 5 random computers randomly hung 2 or 3 times per day (some computers never expericend this problem.). In our case mouse and keyboard disabled and the only way to getting of from the problem, was restarting the system! we have last update of BitDefender!  do you find the origin of the problem?

Comment: `Microsoft will never call out the misbehaving applications` This goes both ways. Sometimes 3rd party apps expose genuine bugs in the core implementation, yet MS would phrase the fix description as to obliquely blame it on some app that did in fact follow the published APIs, but was just off the beaten path.

Answer (score 0):

After configuring Symbols you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check the stack of the hung thread to see which file is causing this delay; do 1, 2, 10, 16, 17, 18 of http://www.solsem.com/lab-setup.html first.

Then, when the hang occurs you can double click on Explorer.exe, go to the Threads view and check the Stack of the threads to see which file or application could be causing this, if you have problems doing that you can try this forum: http://forum.sysinternals.com/troubleshooting_forum6.html

Comment: As i said, i wasn't experiencing the issue. If i was, i would have debugged it. And since the update my colleagues are no longer experiencing it. Like i said in the question: i'm only looking to assign blame, and to be condescending and insulting towards a company and its products.

Comment: You can't do nothing more than going to the list of shell extensions Explorer uses, or the DLL injections that are occuring at Explorer.exe. You didn't say that the update was being istalled so I thought that you still had the ability to troubleshoot this issue... Which you actually still have, you could remove the update and wait for the problem to occur again an then debug it with the method described above. But well, it's patched now and up-to-date computers won't see this problem anymore. It might have been a bug in Explorer.exe that acts weird or times out when some parameters are given.